# Add variable number of array elements together at each loop iteration

Tags: c++, c, signal-processing

I'm looking for a looping structure to acomplish the below task:

At each loop iteration I need to add a loop+1 number of indices together up to maxArrSize(5 in this case) then --maxArrSize number of indices together from there until maxArrSize==0.
This is cross correlation of two arrays, I have everything up to the addition of each array shift handled.

Here's a scaled down example to help explain what I'm looking for:

```
// ------------------------- DON'T FOCUS ON THIS ------------------------
int8 a[5] = { 1, 5, 4, 7, 8 };
int8 b[5] = { 2, 0, 1, 3, 3 };
int maxArrSize = sizeof(a) >= sizeof(b) ? sizeof(a) : sizeof(b);
int8 twoDtemp[5][5];
int8 temp[28] = { };
int8 xCorr[5*2-1] = { };
int x = 5;

// Fill the multiplication matrix
for (int loop = 0; loop < maxArrSize; loop++)
{
    for (int nested = 0; nested < maxArrSize; nested++)
    {
        twoDtemp[loop][nested] = b[iterate] * a[nested];
    }
    iterate--;
}
// Copy into a single dimension array
memcpy(temp, twoDtemp, sizeof(a)*sizeof(a));

// ------------------------- END DON'T FOCUS ON THIS --------------------


// ---------------------------- FOCUS ON THIS ---------------------------
// Below is where I want create a loop that will do the below for me.
// So I don't have to write the entire addition table.


// Cross-Correlate
//xCorr[0] = temp[0]; // +sizeof(b)-1 right, +1 down
//xCorr[1] = temp[1]+temp[5];
//xCorr[2] = temp[2]+temp[6]+temp[10];
//xCorr[3] = temp[3]+temp[7]+temp[11]+temp[15];
//xCorr[4] = temp[4]+temp[8]+temp[12]+temp[16]+temp[20];
//xCorr[5] = temp[9]+temp[13]+temp[17]+temp[21]; // +sizeof(b)-1 right, +sizeof(b) down
//xCorr[6] = temp[14]+temp[18]+temp[22];
//xCorr[7] = temp[19]+temp[23];
//xCorr[8] = temp[24];
// ------------------------ END FOCUS ON THIS ---------------------------

// ****************
// **** UPDATE ****
// ****************
// --------------------------- SOLUTION ---------------------------------
for (int split = 0; split < 2 * x - 1; ++split)
{
    int z = (split < x) ? 0 : split - x + 1;

    for (int j = z; j <= split - z; ++j)
    {
        xCorr[split] += twoDtemp[j][split - j];
    }
}
// ------------------------ END SOLUTION --------------------------------
```

Your help is appriciated, I will explain more as needed.

Comment: Note that e.g. `sizeof(a)` returns the size of the array `a` in ***bytes***, not in the number of elements. Assuming that `sizeof(int) == 4` (which is common) then your arrays will be `20` bytes. If you loop over `20` "elements" then you will go out of bounds of the arrays.

Comment: Also note that since both arrays are the same size, then `sizeof(a) == sizeof(b)` is always true.

Comment: Think about this increasing after the looping structure is defined. That's all I need. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Then you must use pointers, and `sizeof` on a pointer gives you the size of the *pointer* and not the memory it points to. So either case your code is flawed and possibly dangerous. If you use actual arrays then you already know the number of elements in them. And if you use pointers then you need to keep track of the number of elements some other way. And remember that passing an array to a function will make the array decay to a pointer (to the arrays first element).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Please review the updated example. If you can't help with the topic then please move on.

Comment: Save yourself some frustration, switch to `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Vimal's answer, what you want to sum up the diagonals of the 2D matrix.  This is more apparent if you change your current code to set `xCorr` based on the 2D array `twoDtemp` instead of the 1D array `temp`:

```
xCorr[0] =  twoDtemp[0][0];
xCorr[1] =  twoDtemp[0][1] + twoDtemp[1][0];
xCorr[2] =  twoDtemp[0][2] + twoDtemp[1][1] + twoDtemp[2][0];
xCorr[3] =  twoDtemp[0][3] + twoDtemp[1][2] + twoDtemp[2][1] + twoDtemp[3][0];
xCorr[4] =  twoDtemp[0][4] + twoDtemp[1][3] + twoDtemp[2][2] + twoDtemp[3][1] + twoDtemp[4][0];
xCorr[5] =  twoDtemp[1][4] + twoDtemp[2][3] + twoDtemp[3][2] + twoDtemp[4][1];
xCorr[6] =  twoDtemp[2][4] + twoDtemp[3][3] + twoDtemp[4][2];
xCorr[7] =  twoDtemp[3][4] + twoDtemp[4][3];
xCorr[8] =  twoDtemp[4][4];
```

Note that one of the two indexes starts at either 0 or 4 (i.e. the limits of the array dimensions), and that one goes down and one goes up until the limit is hit on the other side.

So you need an outer loop to go through each diagonal, and an inner loop that goes up/down each index.

You can do this as follows:

```
int matrix[len][len];    // len is an int defined elsewhere

...

// populate matrix

...

int i, j
for (i=0; i < len*2 - 1; i++) {
    int min =  (i - (len-1) > 0) ? i - (len-1) : 0;
    xCorr[i] = 0;
    for (j=0; j<=i-min && j<len-min; j++) {
        xCorr[i] += matrix[j+min][i-min-j];
    }
}
```

The `min` variable dictates the starting X index.  On the first `len` diagonals it is 0, after that it is the diagonal number minus `len`.

The inner loop starts the X index at `min` and the Y index at the diagonal number minus `min`.  Then the X index goes up and the Y index goes down until either the X index hits `len-1` or the Y index hits 0.

Comment: You were just a little faster than me on this! Thank you for your help and @Vimal thank you fo your hint, it got me to the answer that beat me to. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I will give a hint -

```
0   1  2  3  4
5   6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

So `xCorr` is just diagonal sum of indices. See for `xCorr[2] = temp[2] + temp[6] + temp[10]` now look number `2,6,10` in above matrix, you see ? Similar is for all indices of `xCorr`.

So it's just about finding diagonal sum in that way. Try to find the logic, it will be good brain exercise.